# Need to optimize mssql query for fastest speed

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, query-optimization

Please help me on below query to optimize. "#oz" temp table has 16000 rows. Now this query runs for about 14 seconds.

### [DOWNLOAD QUERY WITH DATA](http://uncia.mn/_updateapp/sqlquery1.rar)

```
create table #oz (
    id int, from_sto_move bit, product_id int, [date] datetime,
    qty_orlogo decimal(30, 10), qty_zarlaga decimal(30, 10), cost_prev decimal(30, 10)
)

print 'Query started on: ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 126)
select
    oz1.product_id,
    oz1.id,
    oz1.from_sto_move,
    sum(isnull(oz2.qty_orlogo, 0) - isnull(oz2.qty_zarlaga, 0))
        qty_oz,
    oz1.cost_prev
from
    #oz oz1 left join
    #oz oz2 on
        oz1.product_id = oz2.product_id and
        oz1.[date] > oz2.[date]
group by oz1.product_id, oz1.id, oz1.from_sto_move, oz1.cost_prev
print 'Query finished on: ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 126)
```

---

I need less than 5 seconds.
Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL server?

Comment: MSSQL2008 R2 Enterprice

Comment: I noticed that `id` is not unique in the example-data, is this by accident or 'expected behavior' ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add an Clustered Index to the Table on the column "product_id" and include "id" and "from_sto_move" in it. And let me know if that helps.

Can you please add another index to the table  ?

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_oz_7_148195578__K3_K1_K2_K7_4] ON [dbo].[oz]
(
[product_id] ASC,
[id] ASC,
[from_sto_move] ASC,
[cost_prev] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [date]) WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is the second index which you can create :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_oz_7_148195578__K3_K4_5_6] ON [dbo].[oz]
(
[product_id] ASC,
[date] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [qty_orlogo],
[qty_zarlaga]) WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and let me know how well that works.

Comment: running time declined to 7 seconds. it worked great.

Comment: but i am afraid of 7 seconds is not enough. requirement is less than 5 seconds

Comment: i edited my question. Now you can download full query with full data.

Comment: I got an improvement of around 75% :)

Comment: Did you get any improvement ?

Comment: Replace the correct values in the above solution. 

I had oz instead of a temporary table in my query. ( #oz)

Comment: I did as you suggested and result is 7 seconds. Maybe it is the minimum. Your help was great. thanks Ram!

Comment: Okay..  14 secs to 7 secs.. :)

You can make this as solution if you wish. :)

Answer (score 0):

The only expanded suggestion I have is to build a covering index, but then is the engine taking more time to prepare the index than run the query?

try creating an index on (product_id, [date], id, from_sto_move, cost_prev ).

Since this is a #temp table, I don't think that making the index clustered is critical as opposed to just having the key elements for the join/group.  Date is critical component to the join.

Also, you are showing the create temp table for #oz, but not how you are populating it.  Perhaps going up one level on how it is populated from the raw original data might also help by preparing in a pre-sorted order to temp table, then self-joining the results you are looking for.

Comment: I edited my question. Now you can download full query with full data. Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work quite well, and from what I can tell it returns the exact same results (`CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*))` over both resultsets returns the same value).

```
;WITH src
  AS (SELECT oz1.product_id,
             oz1.id,
             oz1.from_sto_move,
             qty_oz = ISNULL((SELECT sum(isnull(oz2.qty_orlogo, 0) - isnull(oz2.qty_zarlaga, 0))  
                                FROM  #oz oz2 
                               WHERE oz2.product_id  = oz1.product_id 
                                 AND oz2.[date] < oz1.[date]), 0),
             oz1.cost_prev
        FROM #oz oz1)

SELECT product_id,
       id,
       from_sto_move,
       sum(qty_oz) as qty_oz,
       cost_prev
  FROM src
 GROUP BY product_id,
          id,
          from_sto_move,
          cost_prev
```

The 'great' thing about it is that it doesn't rely on any indexes; in fact it even works quite well directly on the heap too so you don't lose time creating indexes.

That said, even when there is no real PK on a table (temp-table or not); I'd always make sure to add at least an `IDENTIY()` column when creating the table and put the clustered index on it **before** loading the data. In my experience it makes loading the data slightly faster.

Comment: Strange but true, this works best if there is NO index on #oz. When I add the index on `product_id` and `from_sto_move` the query takes about 4 seconds; when I don't have an index it takes just under 2 seconds. SQL can be weird sometimes =)

Comment: Your query runs magically just 3 seconds. I never expect it. Thanks for your great help!

Comment: Glad it helped you out. FYI, I wouldn't have expected to have this much an effect either, but luckily you provided the data to play with.